Sending bitcoin to new address using Bitcoin-Qt 0.8.6
I have an old tablet with Bitcoin QT. When I go to set an address to send bitcoins, it doesn't let me fill in the entire address. It allows me 4-5 characters less. How do I allow a longer address? The software is Windows 8, Bitcoin QT 0.8.6

I've taken the liberty to summarize the problem better in the title. Feel free to revert/edit if you disagree.

Bitcoin-Qt 0.8.6 is over ten years old. Based on your mention of "longer addresses", I am guessing that you are trying to send to a native segwit address (starting with bc1…). The segwit protocol upgrade activated only seven years ago. Your software does not support the new address format, because it was released years before the new address format was introduced.
I see three approaches from simplest to more effort that may resolve your issue:

Request a "legacy address" from the recipient
Many wallets and services support generating old address types to mitigate this form of incompatibility. Check if you can get a "legacy address", "Pay to Public Key Hash (P2PKH)", or "Pay to Scripthash (P2SH)" address from the recipient. Your software will be able to send to those.
Forward the payment with a second wallet
You could install a second wallet on your phone or a computer that can generate legacy addresses for receiving and also has support for sending to the recipient. Then you send your funds first from the old wallet to this new wallet and forward it from the new wallet to the recipient.
Upgrade your software
Any version of Bitcoin Core (which Bitcoin-Qt is part of) can import all prior versions’ wallets. Make one or several backups of your wallet, then import a copy of your wallet into a new version of Bitcoin Core on the same or another machine. The new software version will be able to import or migrate the wallet, and will also be able to send to modern addresses.

Either way, I would recommend making a backup of your wallet if you have not made one yet, as you appear to be using a device that may be at least 10 years old.

Is it possible to send to a new address from the console? What are the steps?

Your Bitcoin Core version is older than the segwit soft fork, so it does not support sending to the newer output types.
